material ui stacked bar chart - tooltip - overall total
This is the what it look like, what I like to do is show the total somewhere here
I can get the total of them, but I don't know how to show them
I have used valueFormatter in the series but it changes every tooltip value so like
label 1 - 1 abc
label 2 = 2 abc
I also tried valueFormatter in the yAxis or xAyis but if the numbers were large, the text won't fit
enter image description here
maybe if i can only show F - 12 or M - 12 in tooltip but not on axis
